# How to add default columns like createdTxStamp and read in ofbiz?

Tags: java, ofbiz

I want to add couple more default columns in tables and read them.

**I tried :**

in ModelEntity.java

```
ModelField newFieldTenantId = ModelField.create(this, "", COMAPNY_ID, "description", null, null, null, false, false, false, true, false, null);
        internalAddField(newFieldTenantId, pkFieldNames);
```

and corresponding declarations.

**Output :**

It Creates default columns in all the tables but can not read the using entity-condition or any....

**Expectation:**

Not only creating the default columns, but they should also be accessed from entity-conditions

Thanks

Comment: I got it working if anybody is interested knowing the solution i can help... not posting here as it is quite a long soln....

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your entities/tables in the corresponding `entitymodel.xml` and restart your OFBiz, you don't have to do anything else to get the four default columns. OFBiz will generate them for you.

Just make sure you have set

```
check-on-start="true"
add-missing-on-start="true"
```

In your datasource in `entityengine.xml`.